# Continuity of the homeomorphic map between $S^n$ and $R^n\cup \infty$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

In topology, the n-dimension Euclidean space with an added point is described as being homeomorphic to the n-sphere.

One possible map that defines the "similarity" would be $f:S^n \mapsto R^n \cup \infty$ given by:
$$ f(x_0,...,x_n) = \begin{cases}  (\frac{x_1}{1-x_0},\frac{x_2}{1-x_0}...,\frac{x_n}{1-x_0})    &\text{ if } x_0 \ne 1\\
          \infty &\text{ if } x_0 = 1\end{cases}$$

The topology on $X^+ = R \cup \{ \infty \}$ is given by the following closure operator $\tau^+ : P(X^+) \to P(X^+)$ on the power set of $X^+$:

$$ \tau^+(S) = \begin{cases}  
\tau (S)    &\text{ if } S \subseteq R^n \text{and bounded}\\
          \tau(S) \cup \{\infty \} &\text{ if S is not bounded and} \subseteq R^n\\
\tau(S - \infty) \cup \{\infty \} &\text{ if } \infty \in S\\
\end{cases}$$
for any set $S \subseteq R^n \cup \{\infty \}$, where $\tau : P(R^n) \to P(R^n)$ is the standard closure operator on $R^n$.
Now I can see that if $x_0 \ne 1$ then this function is clearly continuous as it would be defined by rational functions, but how does one go about proving that the function is continuous when its image is infinity? Similarly what is the process of showing that the inverse function is continuous (I can see that this function is surjective and injective).

Comment: Which topology do you give to $\mathbb R^n \cup \{\infty\}$?

Comment: @mathripper How familiar are you with the notion of (one point) Alexandroff compactifications?

Comment: @ΑΘΩ I haven't come across it yet.

Comment: I voted to close your question because nobody can answer it if you do not tell us which topology you give to $\mathbb R^n \cup \{\infty\}$.

Comment: @PaulFrost ok I will write it as soon as I can (but it should be the usual extended topology I guess).

Comment: It is certainly the topology of the one-point compactification. But this is an **essential information.**

Comment: @mathripper There is no such thing as "the usual extended topology". The only "usual" topological construction that could come to mind when extending $\mathbb{R}^n$ by an exterior $\infty \notin \mathbb{R}^n$ is the Alexandroff compactification that I mentioned above, and this is the only appropriate name under which to reference this construction.

Comment: I retracted my close vote because you tried to give some infomation concerning the topology on $X = \mathbb R^n \cup \{\infty\}$. However, it is still not really clear which subsets of $X$ are **open**. Please be precise. Starting with **any** $S \subset X$ does not make much sense to explain when $S$ should be open. So give us a definition in the form $S \subset X$ is open if  ...

Comment: @PaulFrost I'm a bit confused. If $\tau(S)$ is the standard topology on $\mathbb{R^n}$ then defining the closure operator as above doesn't define what are the open sets?

Comment: In fact, what is said is that if you do not know which topology is given on the set $\mathbb{R}^n\cup\{\infty\}$, and by topology we mean who are the open subsets, then we can not answer you. If you know the Alexandroff topology of one point compactification, and understand it clearly, it will be trivial, as this topology is defined to make the stereographic projection an homeomorphism.

Comment: @DIdier_ but my point is that the specifying the closure operator as above is equivalent to specifying the open sets.

Comment: @mathripper are you sure this is defines a topology? It seems that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not a part of your topology $\tau^+$, but it should be open in the compactification. Maybe I don't understand what you stated.

Comment: Okay, it seems that $\tau$ denotes the closure operator of $\mathbb R^n$, but you didn't say this in your definition. The formulation "$\tau((S)$ is the standard topology on  $\mathbb R^n$" is not adequate to explain what you mean.

Comment: Do you know how to define open sets based on a closure operator? And which definition of continuity do you use?

Comment: @DIdier_ It is okay, $\mathbb R^n$ is not closed in the one point compactification.

Comment: @PaulFrost Ok so I guess here are defined closed subsets?

Comment: @DIdier_ Yes. It is perhaps unusual to introduce at topology by a closure operator, but it is a valid approach.

Answer (score 1):

To see the continuity, you have to show that if you have a sequence $x_k=(x_{k,0},x_{k,1},\ldots,x_{k,n})$ with $x_{k,0}\to1$ then there is some $j\in\{1,\dotsc,n\}$ such that $(x_{k,j}/(1-{x_{k,0}}))_k$ is unbounded.

To see that the inverse $g=f^{-1}$ is continuous, it suffices to show that preimages of open sets are open or (passing to the complements) that preimages of closed sets are closed. But preimages of closed subsets under $g$ are images of compact sets under $f$. So it suffices to show that compact subsets of the image space are closed. Depending on what you know already about topology, this might be trivial (e.g. it follows from the fact that the image space is Hausdorff).